# Proper way to mock a collection

Tags: collection, magento2.4, unit-tests, mocks

I've asked this once already here: [How to properly use getCollectionMock](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/120209/146)
But that was for a different reason, and in the meantime the  `Magento\Framework\TestFramework\Unit\Helper\ObjectManager` is deprecated so this code is not recommended anymore.

```
$om = new \Magento\Framework\TestFramework\Unit\Helper\ObjectManager($this);
$collectionMock = $om->getCollectionMock(\Collection\Class\Here, [$obj1, $obj2]);
```

where `$obj1, $obj2` are objects returned when iterating through the mocked collection

How can I mock a collection without the use of unit test object manager helper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK. the answer was so obvious but I missed it somehow.
What I needed to do is to check what exactly `Magento\Framework\TestFramework\Unit\Helper\ObjectManager::getCollectionMock()` does.

And this is how it can be done inside a unit test class

```
    $collectionMock = $this->getMockBuilder(\Collection\Class\Here::class)
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->disableOriginalClone()
        ->disableArgumentCloning()
        ->disallowMockingUnknownTypes()
        ->getMock();
    $iterator = new \ArrayIterator([$obj1, $obj2]);
    $collectionMock->expects($this->any())->method('getIterator')->will($this->returnValue($iterator));
```